# Does a line of salt prevent a baned entity from crossing?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e

If a being that can have banes (such as a Strix, spirit, ghost, etc) has a bane of salt, would a line of salt on a doorway prevent it from entering (like in Supernatural), or would it essentially have to be a wall of salt?

Comment: Couldn't a ghost or spirit simply go around the line of salt, through a wall? Your question appears to be "can they fly over it", but incorpeal beings could just as easily go around it.

Comment: @Theik in most magic universes I encountered, ring on the ground was working as a cylinder, stretching up. Is it the case in WoD? I'd like to know, too. But true enough, it was always a circle, in all books and games I remember. Usually it didn't even need to be exactly round, but it had to be closed, precisely to prevent creature from simply going around.

Comment: @Theik it's also worth noting that the Strix specifically aren't ephemeral (like ghosts and spirits), but like them they happen to have banes

Comment: ghosts in nWoD can't fly, not can most types of spirits. They hug the ground, unless there is different ground in the twilight

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer, it appears, is, it depends, just pouring salt doesn't appear to be quiet enough, though if you read abjuration it really isn't much more. I think it's basically that spilled salt wouldn't do it as it lacks intent.

God Machine Chronicle p232, rules update appendix **Warding and Binding**

> Instead of confronting the entity directly as in abjuration, the ritualist marks the boundary she intends to protect
>   with the entity’s bane. She doesn’t have to mark a complete
>   boundary — her concept of the area she’s protecting is what’s
>   important. Marking doors and windows with lamb’s blood
>   to keep out a spirit that can’t touch it will prevent that spirit
>   from simply floating through the wall while in Twilight, and
>   carefully drawing a sigil on the floor will serve to trap the
>   angel whose name it is.

Comment: I think you've got it. Drawing the boundary in salt is enough to demarcate it, preventing the spirit from floating through.